# Django-Haystack autocomplete---get distinct results

Tags: autocomplete, distinct, django-haystack

I would like my autocomplete results with django-haystack to be distinct. However, if multiple objects in my database have a certain value for an attribute on which I am autocompleting, the result appears multiple times.

I am using Haystack with solr as my backend. My query, as in the tutorial, looks like:

```
SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto=request.GET.get('q', ''))[:5]
```

I'm new to Haystack, and the documentation seems limited.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!